# Trying to Display Content Once Image is hovered over

Tags: html, css

Just making this from scratch for a project of mine. I am wanting to create a hover affect on an image that then displays content about that image on top. The image would dim on the hover and the content would then display above it.

The problem that I am having is the content is going off the opacity of its parent div. How do I make the child div not get affected by the opacity property?

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="featured-home-bg">
            <div class="background-content">
                <div class="featured-home-content">
                    <h2>Home Name</h2>
                    <p>Lorem Ipsum leo dormit tan loius ov noetermit.</p>
                </div><!--- end featured-home-content --->
            </div><!--- end background-content --->
</div><!--- end featured-home-bg --->
```

Here is my CSS:

```
.featured-home-bg {
    background: url(../images/home-1.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: 400px;
    height: 300px;
}

.background-content {
    background-color: #000;
    height: 225px;
    width: 400px;
    opacity: 0;
}

.background-content:hover {
    opacity: 0.6;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.50s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.50s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: opacity 0.50s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.50s ease-in-out;
}

.featured-home-content {
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
}

.featured-home-content:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here this is the way to do that as @Henric Åkesson said but here with every div

html

```
> <div class="image"><!-- image can be placed here --> <div
> class="imagehover">text </div></div>
```

css

```
.image {    
width: 400px;
height: 400px;
background-color: red;
line-height: 400px;
}
.imagehover{
width: 400px;
height: 400px;
background:; 
opacity:0;
text-align: center;
font-size:20px;
transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.image:hover .imagehover { 
transition: 0.2s;
opacity:1;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
text-align:justify; 
color:white;
font-size:25px; 
font-weight:700; 
font-family: "apercu",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; 
text-align: center;
line-height: 400px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/d6yhnmnf/5/

Answer (score 0):

I think you would like to have the code something like this?

```
.featured-home-bg:hover .background-content {
opacity: 0.6;
}
```